Flutter: in_app_purchase in android - Renewal PurchaseDetails not captured by IAP purchaseStream listener No PurchaseDetails receive
IAP subscriptions and consumable products work fine on iOS, and consumable products also work well on Android. However, on Android, only the initial subscription is captured, while subsequent renewals are not. These renewals should be picked up by the purchaseStream listener, but they are not being received.
The IAP purchaseStream listener should receive a PurchaseDetails every 5 minutes for monthly subscription, as the Play Store can send renewal notifications via email.
